# JavaScript type coercion with strings and indexing

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, type-coercion

In the below snippet why does `whatDoesItDo()` function return "fail" as string?
It would be helpful if someone can explain the concept behind such behavior.

```js
function whatDoesItDo() {

  return (![] + [])[+[]] + (![] + [])[+!+[]] +
    ([![]] + [][
      []
    ])[+!+[] + [+[]]] + (![] + [])[!+[] + !+[]];

}

function result() {

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = whatDoesItDo();

}

result();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p id="result"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is your  expected output?

Comment: "fail" is the output.But the question is why?

Comment: Puzzles should go to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If only it was easier to search for these kind of questions. Questions like this one have been asked too many times.

Comment: @FelixKling: Maybe we should add a tag, like `javascript-coercion-games`, so we can find them later. :-)

Comment: I was confused as to what to search on google

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I added type-conversion. At least narrows it down.

Comment: @Flake: Yeah, really hard to search these.

Comment: @FelixKling: I ended up calling it [`js-type-coercion-puzzles`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/js-type-coercion-puzzles/info). We'll see if it survives. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're seeing the effects of A) Type coercion, B) Indexing into strings using `[]`, and C) String concatenation.

Let's look at the first bit:

```
(![] + [])[+[]]
```

`![]` gives us `false` because `[]` is a "truthy" value that coerces to `true` when tested as a boolean, and so `![]` is `false`.

Then we add `[]` to it, which turns them both into strings because the `+` operator coerces both its arguments to strings if either of them isn't a number (if both are numbers, it adds), giving us `"false"` (because `[].toString()` is `[].join()` which is `""`).

So now we have `"false"`.

Then, `+[]` is `0` because it coerces the empty array to a number, which takes it through being a string (`""`), and `+""` is `0`.

Finally, that value is used on `"false"`:  `"false"[0]` is `"f`".

And so on, the rest of it is just variations on that theme. (`!+[]` is `true`, which matters later.)

Comment: '+' operator takes two arguments.....so if one is 0 then what does it take as second argument

Comment: @Flake That's not addition operator, it's [asm.js type annotation](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#parameter-type-annotations).

Comment: @Flake: There are two `+` operators in JavaScript (and most other programming languages syntactically derived from the language B): The [*unary* `+`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) (unary = takes one operand) and the [*binary* `+`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) (binary = takes two operands). The `+` in `+[]` is the unary `+`. In JavaScript, pretty much its sole job is to coerce its operand to a number.

Comment: This link has good explanation for unary + http://frontendplay.com/2013/05/25/plus-sign-javascript/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, I have to ask - totally out of curiosity after finding your question on meta. I get were the `f`, `a` and `l` come from "casting" bool to string and only getting the n-th character of that string. But where does the `i` come from ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be `[][[]]` is `[][""]` which is *undef**i**ned* :-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski ah, yes clever one, thanks for your lights.

Comment: @b.enoit.be: What Lucas said. :-) Specifically, `([![]] + [][[]])` ends up being `falseundefined`. We index into that with `+!+[] + [+[]]`, which ends up being `"10"`. The 11th character of `falseundefined` is `i`.