# empty javascript array considered string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is an empty JavaScript array considered a string?  When I try to do an increment operation on an empty array it returns `"1"`.  I am also curious why it doesn't run the catch block.

```js
let x=[]

try {
  x=x+1 
} catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}

console.log( typeof x, x);
```

Comment: Nope, the array is being coerced in to being a string by the `+` (concatenation) operator.

Comment: The + operator is not defined for arrays. What happens is that Javascript converts arrays into strings and concatenates those.

Comment: if you want to add to the array you need to `.push`

Comment: Please have a read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition

Comment: I feel like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875019/javascript-type-coercion-with-strings-and-indexing) might relate better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` operator coerces the array and the number to a string first. This calls `toString` on the array, which calls `join` without any arguments, resulting in `""`. The result of concatenating `""` and `"1"` is `"1"`.

Comment: Would it not be the result of concatenating `""` and `1`, rather than `"1"`?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Both operands are coerced to string first.

Comment: okay i see now that both operands are converted to their primitives first.  An object's primitive is it's default value, in this cast the array default method is `toString()`.  Am I getting this right?

Comment: @bfmcneill The `+` operator will coerce both operands to string if they are not both numbers.